# Trouble Refreshing chat

Tags: chat, adapter

Hell all... am struggling with this simple chat app...am just practicing..... am having trouble getting the chat list to auto refresh...only way I see the latest message I sent is to close app and reopen...

`

```
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String>listloader;
TextView editmsg;
Button convosend;
private static Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(this, "", "");


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    final EditText editmsg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editmsg);

    final Button convosend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.convosend);

    final ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    getActionBar().setTitle("Cyber chat");

handler =new Handler();

convosend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {



    //button send




        String  msg= editmsg.getText().toString();


        ParseObject users = new ParseObject("Users");
        users.put("name", "mckeny");
        users.put("age", "26");
        users.put("gender", msg);

        users.saveEventually();



}}); handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()

        {   

ParseQuery <ParseObject> q=ParseQuery.getQuery("Users");

    q.setLimit(30);

q.orderByDescending("createdAt");
q.whereEqualTo("name","mckeny");
    q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
    {
        @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject>u,ParseException e)
    {
        ArrayList<String>list =new ArrayList<String>();

    for(ParseObject user:u)
        {
        list.add(user.getString("name"));
            list.add(user.getString("gender"));}
        listloader = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list,list);

        listloader.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(listloader);


    }

    });


    }},1000);


    }}
```

Comment: Just an advice: Please try to improve the code example format, remove those unnecessary lines, and write some more lines about what exact problem your facing. Further more is this C#? Java? Android? Tag your language.

Comment: Its Java+android...I don't know how to explain better but thanks....I just need the new data to refresh automatic... without have to close the app and reopen it to see the new data...

Answer (score -1):

In order to see latest messages instantly without necessity to close and then open your app you need to set up and use a message listener. Here is an example how receiving messages is implemented in [ConnectyCube](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/messaging?id=sendreceive-chat-messages) chat:

```
IncomingMessagesManager incomingMessagesManager = chatService.getIncomingMessagesManager();

incomingMessagesManager.addDialogMessageListener(new ChatDialogMessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(String dialogId, ConnectycubeChatMessage message, Integer senderId) {

    }

    @Override
    public void processError(String dialogId, ChatException exception, ConnectycubeChatMessage message, Integer senderId) {

    }
});
```